# Corda test net deploy node version 4.0

Tags: corda

https://testnet.corda.network/dashboard

I created original cordapp, This corda version is 4.0,

I want to deploy this node on a test net,
Is this possible?

and, How should I check that a node is participating in a test net?

■ I referred to the following

https://docs.corda.net/head/azure-vm-explore.html

https://docs.corda.net/head/testnet-explorer-corda.html

https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/docs/source/testnet-explorer-corda.rst

I thank you in advance for your reply

Answer (score 0):

(Developer Relations at R3 here)

https://docs.corda.net/head/corda-testnet-intro.html has more information on how to join the testnet.

Corda does require you to run your own node (ie server), this could be hosted on any cloud providers, and we have detailed instructions available for Azure, AWS and GCP: https://docs.corda.net/deploy-to-testnet-index.html

Once you've deployed a node to a server, added your CordApp to it, and went through the joining testnet instructions, the node should start up cleanly without any errors -- which will tell you the app was successfully deployed.

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to StackOverflow. According to the [twitter profile](https://twitter.com/chabotc) that you linked in your profile, you're affiliated with Corda. StackOverflow's [promotion guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) require that you disclose your affiliation if you are related to a product or service that you mention in your answers. Would it be possible to [edit] your posts to mention that you work for Corda? Thanks

Comment: Awesome, thankyou for the prompt reply! Would it be possible for you to also update your other posts to include the disclosure as well?

Comment: this corda.jar is corda 3.0, 
Is it possible to run Cordapps deployed in Corda 4.0 on Corda 3.0? 
Wait for Corda 4.0 to be provided to the test net,

Thank you for your reply!